# Search for partially matching pattern of a strings in a file and replace it

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I need to find the line that starts with the below specified input strings in the file and replace the contents of the file when it matches partially.

Input parameter:

Scenario-1:

```
STRING="user::r--,user::ourfrd:r--"
```

Scenario-2:

```
STRING="user::r--"`
```

Input data available in `file.txt`:

```
# file: /local/Desktop/myfile
# owner: me
# group: mygroup
user::rwx
user:myfrd:rwx
user:hisfrd:r-x
group::r-x
group:mygroup:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

I have applied the below logic to eliminate comma if available in the string and then kept each string in array. Then I tried to search it in the file,but replacing the contents in the file is not working as expected.

For Scenario-1:

```
#/bin/bash
STRING="user::r--,user:ourfrd:r--"
array=`echo $STRING | awk -F ',' '{ s = $1; for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) s = 
s "\n"$i; print s; }'`
for word in ${array}
do
        sed -r -e 's/${array}[^{array}]+//g' file.txt
done
```

For Scenario-2:

```
#/bin/bash
STRING="user::r--"
array=`echo $STRING | awk -F ',' '{ s = $1; for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) s = 
s "\n"$i; print s; }'`
for word in ${array}
do
        sed -r -e 's/${array}[^{array}]+//g' file.txt
done
```

Expected Results - Modified File data

For Scenario-1:

```
# file: /local/Desktop/myfile
# owner: me
# group: mygroup
user::r--
user:myfrd:rwx
user:hisfrd:r-x
user:ourfrd:r--
group::r-x
group:mygroup:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

Note: In the above result, the string "user:ourfrd:r--" is added newly to the file since it is not available already in file. Only the partially matching strings to be replaced like how we have "user::rwx" exists in file and the first few characters "user::" which is getting matched with new input parameter "user::r--"

For Scenario-2:

```
# file: /local/Desktop/myfile
# owner: me
# group: mygroup
user::r--
user:myfrd:rwx
user:hisfrd:r-x
group::r-x
group:mygroup:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

Comment: You posted expected result, but it's unclear - what is the input? Don't use \` - they are unreadable and are discouraged. Use `$( .. )` instead. Don't use upper case variables - they are by convention reserved for exported variables, it's easy to cause problems  ex. `PATH`. `echo $STRING | awk -F ','.. ` - just `<<<"$string" tr ',' ' '`

Comment: Ooooooch. So you want to find the line that starts with `user::` and then replace the line with the rest of the input string `user::r--` ? Why not just compare the first and second field? Why do you want "match patrially" - you want to match exactly first two field? Then it's just `awk -F':' '$1 == something && $2 == something { $3 = new_value }'`

Comment: Exactly. you are right, that i what im trying for.

Comment: @contactaps Please [edit] your question and explain in the text what you want to do instead of writing this in a comment. Check if the input is correct. It does not contain `user:ourfrd:something`.

Comment: I think the input `user::ourfrd:r--` is wrong, you meant `user:ourfrd:r--` right? Wait a min, so you want also to add the field if it's missing? Does the order matter? How did you know where to put `user:ourfrd:r--` in scenario 1?

Comment: @Kamil : yes missing input strings needs to be added in the file newly. Order doesnt matter but should group under similar strings

Comment: The "should group" seems to be the hardest to do,unless you re-sort the file after modification. A good middleground would be to edit if it exists, if it doesn't exists add it on the end. Just like `useradd` `passwd` `groupadd` etc. do Any reason why don't you want `setfactl` to take care of it? Apply it to a temp file, apply some modifications, save the acl, remove the temp file.

Comment: @Kamil: Ya even im trying the same. Anyway grouping is not an issue, only replacing and addition of missing strings is not working as expected